# Sublime Text Snippet Substitution RegEx

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, code-snippets

In Sublime Text 2, I'm trying to create a snippet that will wrap each line of a selection in tags, and wrap the complete selection in a containing tag.

```
<container>
    ${SELECTION/^.*/<li>$MATCH<\/li>/g}
</container>
```

It's not working but I'm not sure why! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[${SELECTION/^.*/<li>$0<\/li>/g}]]></content>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
    <description>wrap with li</description>
</snippet>
```

1. You were not wrapping your snippet in CDATA (at least in the example above). Sublime text is very particular about this, unfortunately :(
2. The replacement syntax can be a little funky. `$MATCH` is not working here. Better to use the perl style $0 $1 $2 etc... for groups.

The best guide i've found (so far) that deals with Sublime Snippets and regexes is in the [unnoficial docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html)

Also, make sure that you are putting your snippet in the `packages/User` directory, following the `mysweetsnippet.sublime-snippet` format.

Comment: That is resulting in a tag around the beginning and end of the whole selection, but not each line of the selection. It is odd as I have checked the regex match using 'find' and it is matching each line.

Comment: Hmm. I will look into the line-by-line thing. My recommendation would be to accomplish this with the [Emmet](http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/#wrapping-individual-lines) (used to be ZenCoding) plugin. That will allow you to wrap individual lines in whatever HTML tag you want with sublime's multi-line editing.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I do use Emmet - it's great, and I think you have just given me an idea...